# How does facebook displays latest news feeds without refreshing the page?

Tags: facebook

The posts displayed in the "News feeds" section and are constantly changing even if we have not refreshed the page, so can anyone tell me how does facebook implements this feature....
Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

Using AJAX, Asynchronous Javascript and XML (http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/)